# PHP/JSON-OOCSS : How to permanently modify CSS file after clicking on any elements?

Tags: php, html, css, interface, admin

I'm on a WebDev formation and I'm already fluent with HTML/CSS. I have a bit of exercising with JS/JSON/AJAX and I'm getting more and more into PHP/SQL. I can have a full website with database, user login and signin space, content like articles and all in database, and full admin interface to manage users, content, etc... Also for how I work, I'm a big fan of the rule of "write on paper and unbuild step by step your problem".
*(This is for what I can do, if it can be useful to you)*

---

**What I'm planning to do** is a kind of "Editor Mode" inside the admin interface that when I'll click on a button, I'll shift in Editor Mode and a top fixed navbar will appear. This navbar is the Editor navbar. From this moment, when I'll hover/click on the elements, properties of the chosen element (h1, img, section, etc) will display in the Editor's navbar and I will be able to change its CSS properties dynamically. The Editor mode staying on all pages work correctly ($_SESSION) and it's pretty easy (for now) to modify my style stored in database (for this I do SQL request in the <style> of my "style.php" file).

---

**What I actually did** is that I have my navbar with form inputs in it (like color picker, for now there's only that, let's stick to one input as a test) and I update in database my style this way :

[Screen capture of source code of sending style in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe8OS.png)

[Screen capture of how does my database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euBXd.png)

The thing is that you can see on code that on this first try, I've set litteral values for the request's arguments and in the end I want to be able to go through all my HTML elements (h1-h6,p,a,etc) in some kind of loop and rewrites all the CSS properties in consequences associated to this element I've modified properties.

---

**My first problem is** that I'm wondering how to manage the whole thing, what kind of process should I use ? Directly modify CSS in "style.php" with no storing in database ? Store in database using JSON to make it simpler (without it, I actually have a lot of line for each value of each property of each selector etc) ?

**My second problem is** that I'm wondering what kind of interaction to do to modify style : if I'm planning to click on elements to get style properties in Editor's navbar, how could I manage <a> links to go from one page to another to continue modifying style on other pages ?
Should I use hover for this situation ? Also I thought to combine both, hovering elements does make appear a gear icon in a corner of the elements and when clicking on it, properties are displayed in Editor's navbar. This way, I can click on <a> links to go from one page to another and still change <a> links' style.

---

This is the situation. I hope I've explained clearly, tell me if not, I can show code if required. Thanks for your time, hoping you could help me to find a way, a process to do what I want.

Comment: Please share more details. Do you have any **specific** question that could be answered?

Comment: My problem concerns more of the process of reflexion about how to do something : I'm kind of lost concerning admininstrator modifying style of website. I want him to have a great liberty about the style but I want to manage back-end so it's not messy with one million of variables and all. My problem is about finding a way to do things and organizing it.

Comment: Then please share more details. There are tons of content management systems out there, why not check how they solve this?

Comment: Edited, I hope it's clearer, don't hesitate to tell me which kind of information is more revelant than other if it can help me to write better questions.